# Don't return api when input reverts to empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am calling an api that return stock info once a user types in a certain symbol. My problem is that once the input clears the original api is called and it returns null because the api returns nothing. If I enter in another symbol it comes up but once the fetch from the cleared input is fetch it returns zero and cancels out the api that called the symbol. Is there some way I can stop this from happening?

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapShot) {
        const { userInput, symbol1 } = this.state;

        if (prevState.userInput !== userInput) {
            fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${userInput}&token=budo2rv48v6spq9og4p0`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(responses => this.setState({
                    symbol1: responses
                }))
        }
        else if (userInput === '' || prevState.userInput === '') {
            return userInput
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your wording, but I think what you want is to just *not* perform the search if the input is empty? If so you need to add that condition to the if statement: `if (prevState.userInput !== userInput && userInput !== '')`

Comment: @Jayce444 Yeah, that's what I want, but what would I return. That's the part that gets me

Comment: You don't return anything from `componentDidUpdate`, it's just a function that's called after the state or props change. It's return value isn't used at all. What were you wanting with a return value?

Comment: @Jayce444 I am trying to stop the api call from fetching. I don't need to return something for it to stop that action.

Comment: Ok then the condition in my comment will stop the API call from fetching if they clear the input. You don't need the `else if` part, you don't need to return anything. If the conditions are met do the call, else do nothing at all

Comment: @Jayce444 That did it, thanks! You helped me yesterday as well. You are a life saver!